# Compare dates in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `ng-show` in a page that I'm creating:

```
<td ng-show="week.EndDate > controller.currentDate">
```

where `week` is an object with a property `EndDate` and `currentDate` is set in my controller:

```
currentDate = new Date();
```

My `ng-show` fails whether I set the dates >, <, or =. I printed out my dates and this is what they are:

week.Date = 2014-11-07
controller.currentDate = 2015-07-09T21:54:40.655Z

I'm not sure if the issue is being caused by the difference in format or not. If so how can I correct this, if not, is there another way to compare dates?

Comment: *currentDate* is a Date object, likely *week.Date* is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either convert your `week.EndDate` string to a `Date` object or wrap your comparison in  a function that converts it to a date.

```
ng-show="convertToDate(week.EndDate) > controller.currentDate"
```

The only thing you need to keep in mind is that if you convert `week.EndDate` permanently to a `Date` object you might need to convert it back to your desired format when you want to store it somewhere for example.